# Setting Up the Action Bar tutorial in Android Atudio

Tags: android, android-studio, toolbar

`Theme.Holo` is used in the tutorial http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/setting-up.html

I'm using Android Studio, and the `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` is the default style used in the `styles.xml`

The emulator gives an error **Unfortunately, Action Bar has stopped** if I comment out `AppCompat` theme in  `styles.xml` and add style `name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar`

How can Android Studio be setup so that Holo is the default theme, or how can the theme be changed to match the tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

Change the default code in styles.xml to:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
```

That does it right? Let me know.

Comment: It works, I found the complete procedure in page 372 of Head First Android Development for AppCompat removal 
1. check codes doesn't reference ActionBarActivity; 
2. change two lines to following: import android.app.Activity;
public class MainActivity extends Activity{ 
3. Change theme in AndroidManifest.xml